# Autocomplete textview with title and subitems

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to achieve  [image: this]

For which i have used a custom array adapter

```
public class SearchItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    List<Object> mObjects;
    private final List<Object> mDepartmentsAll;


    public SearchItemAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mObjects=new ArrayList<>(objects);
        this.mDepartmentsAll=new ArrayList<>(objects);

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType= getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType){
            case 0:
                HearderViewHolder viewHolder=null;
                if (convertView==null){
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_drop_down_header, parent, false);
                    viewHolder = new HearderViewHolder(convertView);
                    SearchableHeaders searchableHeaders= (SearchableHeaders) mObjects.get(position);
                    viewHolder.mHeader.setText(searchableHeaders.getSearchableHeader());
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                StringViewHolder stringViewHolder = null;
                if (convertView==null){
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_drop_down, parent, false);
                    stringViewHolder = new StringViewHolder(convertView);
                    SearchableStrings searchableStrings = (SearchableStrings) mObjects.get(position);
                    searchableStrings.getSearchableString();
                    stringViewHolder.mString.setText(searchableStrings.getSearchableString());
                    convertView.setTag(stringViewHolder);
                }
                break;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mObjects.get(position) instanceof SearchableHeaders){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class HearderViewHolder {
        TextView mHeader;


        public HearderViewHolder(View view) {
            mHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSearchHeader);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                if (resultValue instanceof SearchableHeaders){
                    return ((SearchableHeaders) resultValue).getSearchableHeader();
                } else {
                    return ((SearchableStrings) resultValue).getSearchableString();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                List<String> departmentsSuggestion = new ArrayList<>();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    for (Object department : mDepartmentsAll) {
                        if (department instanceof SearchableStrings){
                            departmentsSuggestion.add(((SearchableStrings) department).getSearchableString());
                        } else if (department instanceof SearchableHeaders){
                            departmentsSuggestion.add(((SearchableHeaders) department).getSearchableHeader());
                        }

                    }


                    filterResults.values = departmentsSuggestion;
                    filterResults.count = departmentsSuggestion.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mObjects.clear();
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // avoids unchecked cast warning when using mDepartments.addAll((ArrayList<Department>) results.values);
                    for (Object object : (List<?>) results.values) {
                        if (object instanceof SearchableStrings){
                            mObjects.add(((SearchableStrings) object).getSearchableString());
                        } else if (object instanceof SearchableHeaders){
                            mObjects.add(((SearchableHeaders) object).getSearchableHeader());
                        }


                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (constraint == null) {
                    // no filter, add entire original list back in
                    for (Object department : mDepartmentsAll) {
                        if (department instanceof SearchableStrings){
                            mObjects.add(((SearchableStrings) department).getSearchableString());
                        } else if (department instanceof SearchableHeaders){
                            mObjects.add(((SearchableHeaders) department).getSearchableHeader());
                        }

                    }
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    class StringViewHolder {
        TextView mString;

        public StringViewHolder(View view) {
            mString = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSearchString);
        }
    }
}
```

I am taking a list of objects, and manipulating view according to the object type.
As the custom array adapter of autocomplete view needs to override `getFilter()` method for it to know our logic for filtering, i have implemented my logic, but when it gets to `convertResultToString` it returns an arraylist of object, In the `performFiltering` function i have returned filtered results containing only strings, so why do i get arraylist ?
Is there any other way of getting such kind of suggestion list ?

Comment: Why using different view types ?? after filter just sort it based on your view type and add header before first item in the list.

Comment: And how do i change the color of the text ?